# iTextSharp AddSection Exception

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm currently writing a piece of code where I am trying to print information onto a PDF file. And my problem is that my `Chapter.AddSection 'Chapter is the variable name for a chapter` is giving me an exception.

```
 If clsPDFSelection.USReturn OrElse clsPDFSelection.OtherInformationRequired OrElse clsPDFSelection.ElectionsAndDisclosures OrElse clsPDFSelection.USStates Then
            doc.NewPage()
            Dim section1 As Section = bookMarkFrontLoad.AddSection(New iTextParagraph("US Return"), 2)
```

So the last line is where I add a section to my doc, and iTextParagraph is a class that I created:

```
Public Class iTextParagraph
   Inherits iTextSharp.text.Paragraph
   Private _smallWhiteFont As New iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 2, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE)
   Public Sub New(ByVal content As String)
       Me.Alignment = 0
       Me.Font = _smallWhiteFont
       Me.Add(content)
   End Sub
End Class
```

So whenever `clsPDFSelection.USStates` is true, the last line under my if statement will produce an "Object reference not set to an instance" exception. But for every other selection in the if statement, the code works fine.

Comment: What is `bookMarkFrontLoad` and is it set as an instance?

Comment: Bruno's question is the place to start. I'd also like to add that instead of subclassing iText's classes that you make (possibly static) factory helper methods instead. They mostly come out the same but because you're introducing your own classes you might find that debugging gets much harder with subclassing. For instance, you could just have a method called `CreateParagraph()` that returns a native iText object with your alignment and font sent.